# motionEvent.action_move not working while return false in setOnTouchListener()

Tags: java, android

I have to return false for handling some other situations. I want to know how `motionEvent.action_move` work correctly while returning false.

```
  parentView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

           /* view.performClick(transparentView);*/
        int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX();
        int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY();


                 switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.e("ACTION_DOWN", "x = " + x + " Y = " + y);
                    pic(x, y);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.e("ACTION_MOVE", "x = " + x + " Y = " + y);
                    pic(x, y);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.e("ACTION_UP", "x = " + x + " Y = " + y);
                    pic(x, y);
                    break;
            }


            return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to implement multitouch features of the whole app so if I return true then activity click is not working. so I have return false.any idea how to implement this